# Using Fetch in ReactJS: Response received successfully but response.ok === false

Tags: reactjs, api, express, fetch-api, http-status-code-400

I'm sending a request from my frontend (ReactJS) to my backend (ExpressJS) with fetch.

**Frontend code:**

```
const submitForm = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_API_URL}/users/login`, {
        body: JSON.stringify({
            username,
            password
        }),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        method: 'POST'
    })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            if (response.ok) return response.json();
            throw new Error('Something went wrong');
        })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
};
```

**Backend code:** (I already use CORS, and the **apiRouter** works well

```
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.use('/api', apiRouter);
```

When I send the request in Postman, it returns a success response. But fetch receives an error

[image]

Below are some more information about the request and response. Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `response.ok = true` if the HTTP status is < 300, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok).

Comment: If there is a network error, you won't even have a response object to process. You'll get `TypeError: Failed to fetch` or the likes.

Comment: Another error just come up to me. I have updated it in the question. Would you bother to help me with that? @HeikoTheißen

Answer (score 0):

"OK" usually means the response is in the 200s, so this is expected for a 400 response. You can read up on HTTP status codes [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)